# Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) RC 1 Mac (Apple Silicon) Preview version crashing on start for first time on MacBook Pro

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, arm64, apple-m1

This is my MacBook Pro details overview:

- Model Name:  MacBook Pro
- Chip:    Apple M1
- Total Number of Cores:    8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency)
- Memory:   8 GB
- System Version:   macOS 11.2.2 (20D80) -- macOS Big Sur

Andriod Studio Preview for Arm64 M1 Chip details are as shown in below image:

[image: Andriod Studio Preview for Arm64 M1 Chip preview]

Crash Error report page after computer restarted:
[image]

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe001a72fc4c): "Kernel stack memory corruption detected"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20D80
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:06:51 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: F78A48EC84D7C3283E7C6C67D00889A7
Kernel UUID: 9FE8C0DA-8ED0-381C-9CEC-2A779F3E1503
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.81.1
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000012b1c000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0019b20000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000013650000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe001a654000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe001a71c000
mach_absolute_time: 0x2a3ddb900f
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x6100b5ec 0x00001c66
  Sleep   : 0x6100cc66 0x000706b2
  Wake    : 0x6100cceb 0x00026015
  Calendar: 0x6100d604 0x00004fb0

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001a885748
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001a886c0c
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001a886c0c
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001a886c0c
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001a886c10
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001a886c10
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001a886c10
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001a886c10
Panicked task 0xfffffe167bef8638: 12426 pages, 43 threads: pid 1278: studio
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe167704ec68, backtrace: 0xfffffe3f538e2df0, tid: 51022
          lr: 0xfffffe001a769fd0  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e2e60
          lr: 0xfffffe001a769d9c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e2ed0
          lr: 0xfffffe001a88bf0c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e2ef0
          lr: 0xfffffe001a87d8b8  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e2fa0
          lr: 0xfffffe001a7237e8  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e2fb0
          lr: 0xfffffe001a769a2c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e3340
          lr: 0xfffffe001a769a2c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e33b0
          lr: 0xfffffe001af0465c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e33d0
          lr: 0xfffffe001a72fc4c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e33e0
          lr: 0xfffffe001acfe04c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e3640
          lr: 0xfffffe001a9a6010  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e37c0
          lr: 0xfffffe001a9a5544  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e3a00
          lr: 0xfffffe001a9be7dc  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e3a50
          lr: 0xfffffe001a9c466c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e3db0
          lr: 0xfffffe001ad667ac  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e3e40
          lr: 0xfffffe001a87d59c  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e3ef0
          lr: 0xfffffe001a7237e8  fp: 0xfffffe3f538e3f00

last started kext at 89562439751: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc  5.0.0 (addr 0xfffffe001a11c000, size 16384)
last stopped kext at 5332651289: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter  1.0 (addr 0xfffffe001a4bc000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 4030.5
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    8.0.3d9
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1677.81.1
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   11.5
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  556.60.1
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleDPDisplayTCON 1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   437.96
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  437.96
com.apple.driver.AppleSummitLCD 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.AGXG13G   172.26.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   376
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  401.63.3
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103  1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSynopsysMIPIDSI   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   310
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  401.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   300.6.1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   223
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    4400.28
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  4400.28
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 4030.5
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   8.0.3d9
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 930.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   900.11
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.3d9
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  8.0.3d9
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  14.32
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    172.26.2
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  172.26.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransportSPI   4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport  4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    4400.35
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   437.96
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 437.96
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    80.34
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 20.23
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   4.52.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH13CameraInterface    2.82.0
com.apple.driver.AppleH10PearlCameraInterface   14.70.0
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.watchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DFR    140.0
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    510.72
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    900.11
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    585
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   8.0.3d9
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.3d9
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.6.0
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    511.60.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  184.40.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   436.40.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   436.40.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   289.3
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    11.1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 299363 (Uncompressed 752448) **
```

My MacBook Pro crashes when I start Android studio Preview version(M1 chip) for first time. It shows error report page after computer restart. Please find all MacBook and Android studio related information above.

I have some questions regarding the same:

1. Why is this crash happening?
2. will this Memory corruption crash issue affect MacBook Performance in future ? Do I uninstall this Android Studio Preview version?
3. can such abrupt Computer restart harm severely to MacBook Memory performance ?
4. Will such memory corruption damage Memory permanently?
5. Is there any settings on MacBook or Android Studio to get read of this system restart crash issue?

Comment: Just update your OS. You're crashing in `null_lookup` and there was a kernel bug that was fixed in nullfs not too long ago, so you're very likely hitting that. As for everything else, I'm voting to close this question because it's too broad, it's not a programming problem and it borders on customer support.

Comment: for questions 2, 3, 4: No, it is almost certainly impossible for this type of issue to cause hardware damage.

Comment: @RyanM Thanks for prompt help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated to latest Android Studio preview release on my MacBook Pro. It's not crashing now. You can find all android studio release and its preview release here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

[image]